# Clearing float issue but specific to webkit browsers

Tags: html, css

I am familiar with the basics of clearing floats but in this case I'm a bit stumped and I hope someone can help me.

For this page I have a container called containerTimeline that is supposed to encompass all the content. The content of course is not encompassed by the container. The weird thing is that on Firefox there is no problem it works as it should but in Safari and Chrome it does not. Does anyone know a reason why? Which one of the browsers is rendering it correctly?

I have a link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/T8n4v/

This is some of the code below:

```
    <div class="containerTimeline">
    <div class="year">
        <header>2012</header>
    <div class="month alt">
    <header>Sep</header>
    <ul class="events">
    <li class="event priority1"></li>
    <li class="event priority3"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <div class="month">
    <header>Oct</header>
    <ul class="events">
    <li class="event priority1"></li>
    <li class="event priority3"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <div class="month alt">
    <header>Nov</header>
    <ul class="events">
    <li class="event priority1"></li>
    <li class="event priority3"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <div class="month">
    <header>Dec</header>
    <ul class="events">
    <li class="event priority1"></li>
    <li class="event priority3"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <div class="month alt">
    <header>Jan</header>
    <ul class="events">
    <li class="event priority1"></li>
    <li class="event priority3"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <div class="month">
    <header>Feb</header>
    <ul class="events">
    <li class="event priority1"></li>
    <li class="event priority3"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    </div><!-- end year -->
</div>
```

And its CSS:

```
    body {
      width: 4800px;
    }
    .containerTimeline {
      outline:1px solid red;
      margin: 20px;
      min-height: 100%;
      position: relative;
      width: auto;
    }
    .containerTimeline .year {
      float: left;
      height: 41px;
      background: #e8e8e8;
    }
    .containerTimeline .year header{
      text-align: center;
      color: #666;
      font-size: 15px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      padding: 10px 0;
    }
    .containerTimeline .month {
      width: 43px;
      float: left;
      background: #fff;
    }
    .containerTimeline .month.alt {
      width: 43px;
      float: left;
      background: #e8e8e8;
    }
    .containerTimeline .month header {
       height: 20px;
       width: 43px;
    }
    .containerTimeline .events {
      margin-top: 10px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .containerTimeline .event {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: 36px;
      height: 36px;
      margin: 20px auto;
      margin-bottom: 25px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      border:1px solid black;
    }
    .group:before,
    .group:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
   }
   .group:after {
    clear:both;
    }​
```

Thanks for your help ahead of time.

Comment: Paste your code here, in addition to providing the Fiddle link.

Comment: try overflow:hidden in the container, it removes the calendar part and just shows the years, is that what you want?

Comment: overflow:auto gets toward what I think you want.  It's kinda tough to tell what's going on the way the markup is formatted. also, you know you have .containerTimeline inside of a .containerTimeline, right?

Comment: I was able to get you partially there by adding `<div style="clear:both"></div>` before closing your final div. Try exploring that route

Comment: Hi, I just pasted some code in here as well and I fixed the double container but still no joy. Why does it work in firefox and not webkit browsers?

Comment: .group:after - where is that class included? I don't see from code above.

Comment: .group:after is part of clearfix it's just a different name. But I didn't apply it to the page. When I do it doesn't work it has pretty much the same effect as adding <div style="clear:both"></div> before closing the final div.

Comment: This? http://jsfiddle.net/T8n4v/2/

Comment: Billy Moat you Rock! Thank you. That is the fix.

Comment: Should I explain what the fix was?

Comment: "Why does it work in firefox and not webkit browsers?" - For the same reason somethings work in IE but not FF or webkit, or some things work in FF and webkit, but not IE. Each rendering engine has it's own rules for displaying your mark-up. In a perfect world those rules would be the same, but in our world they aren't, but they are getting closer.

Comment: "Should I explain what the fix was?" You should let Billy Moat submit it as an answer and explain it so he can get the rep for answering your issue. Also, please see if you can make an even more simplified example so it's easier to understand what the problem and fix actually were.